# Keep my own non-published ios app in my phone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I developed an app to my personal usage, and since this is not a commercial app, I don't want to publish it in AppStore. Also, as this one is currently my only iOS app, I don't want to pay the Apple Developer Program (I am not going to publish any app there anytime soon).

Because of that, to use my app I have sideloaded it in my iPhone from the XCode in my MacBook, but every time I do it, after a few days it keeps being deactivated in my phone and becomes unavailable to use. Is there any way to keep it in my phone without being removed from time to time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to keep it in my phone without being removed from time to time?

Not on a non jailbroken phone, unless you pay the membership fee. That's exactly what the developer membership buys you: the right to run on a device long-term.